# how to delete all lines after a certain string in a file and then add some more lines using python

Tags: python, linux, append

I want to delete all the lines in a file smart.txt and then add some strings of my own. smart.txt contains alot of lines.

I tried

```
import sys
import os

output=[]
f= open(smart.txt, 'r')
for line in f:
 output.append(line)
 if '*** P R O P E R T I E S ***' in line: break
f=open(smart.txt, 'w')
[f.write(data) for data in output]
f.write('*** Inclusions ***\n ')
f.write('*** Permanent  ***\n ')
f.close()
```

I am getting an error

```
f= open(smart.txt, 'r')
NameError: name 'smart' is not defined
```

cannot figure out because smart.txt is present in the same directory.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to wrap in quotes

Comment: @all  Look, i found this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python?rq=1  I hope you get my point! and look the subscribers to this question! ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, wrap what?

Comment: what do you think considering you already accepted and asnwer?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I already considered -2 for that. How about editing your answer for perfect grammer and typos? You did not even bother  to complete the answer... there is no question as stupid mind it, you also learnt it!

Comment: my comment was for those who have issued -1 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `'smart.txt'` instead of `smart.txt` when you're opening the file.
So you would change `f= open(smart.txt, 'r')` to `f= open('smart.txt', 'r')`.

Also you should use `with open('smart.txt', 'r') as f` to automatically close the file when you are done with it.

Tutorial on file io: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)